# Making a table centered in latex?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying the following code to make a table in latex, however the table is out of layout.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Table Title}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& $DOC \in P$  & $DOC \notin P$ \\ \hline
$T \in DOC$ & A & B \\ \hline
$T \notin DOC$ & C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\\[10pt]
\caption*{The caption without a number}
\end{table}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\centering`:

```
\begin{table}
\centering % here
\caption{Table Title}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& $DOC \in P$  & $DOC \notin P$ \\ \hline
$T \in DOC$ & A & B \\ \hline
$T \notin DOC$ & C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\\[10pt]
\caption*{The caption without a number}
\end{table}
```

Result:

[image]